# Cloning github repo and overwriting

Tags: bash, github, gitlab, git-clone, file-move

I'm trying to setup an environment that clones a github project into a gitlab repo directory and overwrites it with the files that exist in that gitlab repo.

A couple questions:

- Is there a better approach than cloning and moving files around? (Perhaps this changes the approach - I only want to track changes to the files that already exist in the gitlab repo)
- Assuming cloning and moving is a good approach, currently it does the opposite in the script below (takes the github clone and moves it into the gitlab repo directory, while I need it to move the existing gitlab files on top of the clone). What would be the correct way to reverse this script?

```
git clone https://github.com/github_project/github_project.git /github_clone
mv /github_clone /gitlab_app
rm -rf /github_clone
```

Comment: Maybe rsync command would be the proper solution in that case. It is very versatile, allows exclusions and options for overwrite existing files or not. To be honest I don't know what are you up to. Can't you just clone the repo to the desired repo? 
git clone https://github.com/github_project/github_project.git /gitlab_app

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will look into rsync. For context, there's a github web app created by another development team that's being essentially forked to create a very similar customized website in gitlab. The gitlab site needs to selectively merge updates done by the other dev team in github. Gitlab contains only site files that have been modified from the github repo. Changes include mostly static content and formatting. I didn't build and not sure about the thinking, but agree it seems easier to clone or 'fork' from github to gitlab.

Comment: Would this be the approach to 'fork' from gitlab to be able to merge updates from github? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973048/forking-git-repository-from-github-to-gitlab

Comment: It needs delve into useful possibilities of forking. You said there was need for selective merges and it might be human factor involved (who or what will decide what merge)? It looks like we enter into the territory of changing particular files (as you stated - changing static content and formatting)?